# How can I use man to lookup cocoa functions like FSEventsCopyUUIDForDevice in os x?

Tags: man

I can use man to look up tranditional posix APIs,

but NOT when I try to look up os x APIs like `FSEventsCopyUUIDForDevice` etc.

What am I missing?